# Sorting Class Objects Stored In Deque

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sorting, deque

I am trying to store email addresses written in a file and sort them by hits in the file.

I am storing the email addresses and the number of hits in a class called emailAddress.

I am managing the members of that class in a Deque in another class called AddressManager.

The sort function I am trying to use is the sort from the algorithm library. [Like this.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0540__STL-Algorithms-Sorting/Sortobjectsstoredindeque.htm)

```
[emailAddress.released() returns the number of hits. addressQueue is my emailAddress Deque]

bool AddressManager::swapTest(const emailAddress& address1, const emailAddress& address2)
{
    cout<<"Comparing: "<<address1.released()<<" to "<<address2.released()<<endl;
    return address1.released()>address2.released();
}
void AddressManager::sortAddresses()
{
    
    sort(addressQueue.begin(),addressQueue.end(),
        swapTest);
}
```

When I compile I get this error:

```
1>c:\workspace\addressmanager.cpp(36): error C3867: 'AddressManager::swapTest': function call missing argument list; use '&AddressManager::swapTest' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\workspace\addressmanager.cpp(36): error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(3639) : see declaration of 'std::sort'
```

Can I pass swapTest to sort, or does it need to be defined outside of AddressManager somehow?
Or could someone suggest a way to implement my own sort in AddressManager and not use the library version at all?

Thanks,
ANkh

Comment: More recent C++ compilers require function pointers to be passed with their full names, e.g. &AddressManager::swapTest, rather than just swapTest. Also, doesn't sort use operator < on the type, rather than a sort function? You may be better off using qsort if you want C-style sorting, rather than via operator overloading. EDIT: there is a 3-param version of sort, using a functor. See: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/stdsort.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define an

```
struct EmailSorter
{
  bool EmailSorter::operator ()(const emailAddress &a, const emailAddress &b) {
    return a.released()>b.released();
  }
};

EmailSorter es;

std::sort( v.begin() , v.end() , es );
```

and pass it to `std::sort`

Or make **swapTest** a static function and do

`std::sort( v.begin() , v.end() , &AddressManager::swapTest );`

Comment: I defined it like this:
`#include "emailAddress.h"
class sortTest
{public:
  bool sortTest::operator ()(const emailAddress &address1, const emailAddress &address2)
  {
    return address1.released()<address2.released();
  }
};`
and used it like this:
`std::sort(addressQueue.begin(),addressQueue.end(),
  sortTest());`

Comment: Are you also calling it as I am ?

Comment: Hi Parapura, I've added how I'm calling it. It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

Either make `swapTest` a `static` function, or use a lambda:

```
sort(addressQueue.begin(),addressQueue.end(),
     [](const emailAddress& address1, const emailAddress& address2)
       { return address1.released() > address2.released(); }
     );
```